# ReplaceWith Jquery issue

Tags: jquery

What I am trying to do is when I select one of the project thumbnails, the video on the right gets replaced, as visualized [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TT89Y.jpg). I have discovered I cannot do it more than once though.

I have been searching on event propagation, and I would have to use $this instead so that everytime I click on a different project, I get to change it to the desired video.

I have done a small hack where I created a hidden div with all the content inside so the replacewith could work, it works one way, but when I do the opposite the buttons don't work anymore. Any suggestions? Many thanks in advance :)

My code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/59qe06m3/).

```js
$(function() {
 
var height =1000;
var animSpeed=1000;
var topArrowbtn = $('.arrowTop');
var bottomArrowbtn = $('.arrowBottom');
var $slider = $('.projectorganizer');
var $slideContainer = $('.SlideContainer',$slider);
var $projects = $('.projectC', $slider); 
var $p1 = $('.pro1');
var $p2 = $('.pro2');

var $project = $('.videoSel');
var $project2 = $('.videoSel2');
var $project3 = $('.videoSel3');
var interval;

 function startSlidingUp() {
 
 $slideContainer.animate({'margin-top': '+=' +50},animSpeed, function(){
  /*if($projects.length == */
  
  
  
  }
 
  );

 }
 
 function changeProject1() {
  $("div.videoSel").replaceWith($project2);
  
 }
 
 function changeProject2() {
  $("div.videoSel2").replaceWith($project3);
  
 }
 
 
 
 $p1
 .on('click',changeProject1);
 
 $p2
 .on('click',changeProject2);
 
 /*check if
3
4
5
6
7
// Attach a delegated event handler
$( "#list" ).on( "click", "a", function( event ) {
    var elem = $( this );
    if ( elem.is( "[here I will check if class name equals to desired]" ) ) {
        elem.attr( "target", "_blank" );
    }
});
});
 */
 
 
 
 
 
});
```

```css
.Projectscontent {
 width: 900px;
 max-height: 450px;
 
 margin: 3% auto;
 text-align: center;
 -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0.000001deg);
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 border-radius: 20px;
}
.projectchooser {
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: #FF9900;
 float: left;
 
}

.projectorganizer{
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
 width:100px;
 margin:25px auto;
 height:250px;
 background-color:#0C3;
 max-width:100px;
 max-height:250px;
}

.arrowTop{
 width:100px;
 height:20px;
 margin-bottom:5px;
 background-color:#FF0;
}

.arrowBottom{
 width:100px;
 height:20px;
 margin-top:5px;
 background-color:#FF0;
 bottom:0;
 position:absolute;
}



.hiddenContent{
 position:absolute;
 overflow:hidden;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 max-width:20px;
 max-height:20px;
 background-color:#0CF;
 z-index:-2;
 
}



.projectC{
width:100px;
height:80px;
margin:2px 0;
background-color:#3FC; 
}

.Desccontent {
 float: left;
}
.ContentTitle {
 background-color: #0CF;
 width: 900px;
 min-height: 50px;
}
.ContentTitleTextContainer {
 max-width: 800px;
 max-height: 50px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.TitleDesc {
 
 min-width: 800px;
 max-width: 800px;
 max-height: 50px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size:24px;
 color: #FFF;
}
.ContentDesc {
 background-color: #0CF;
 width: 900px;
 min-height: 100px;
}
.descP {
 max-width: 800px;
 max-height: 50px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.Pclass {
 line-height: 20px;
 max-width: 800px;
 max-height: 50px;
 margin: 10 auto;
 text-align: justify;
 overflow: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 color: #FFF;
 padding-right: 5px;
}
.videoP {
 -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%);
 border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
 border-top-left-radius: 0px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
 border-top-right-radius: 0px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
 -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
 -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
 -moz-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
 -moz-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
 width: 700px;
 max-height: 300px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: "Inconsolata";
 src: url('Inconsolata.otf');
}

video {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 z-index: -100;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 background-size: cover;
 transition: 1s opacity;
}

.footer {
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
  <div class="Projectscontent">
    <div class="ContentTitle">
      <div class ="ContentTitleTextContainer">
        <p class="TitleDesc">ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"> </div>
 <div class="projectchooser">
      <div class="projectorganizer">
        <div class="arrowClass">
          <div class="arrowTop"></div>
          <div class="arrowBottom"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="SlideContainer">
          <li class="projectC pro1"></li>
          <li class="projectC pro2"></li>
          <li class="projectC pro3"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="videoP">
      <div class="videoSel">
        <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/152053434"?autoplay=0&loop=0&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0 width="700" height="300" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ContentDesc">
      <div class="descP">
        <p class="Pclass">fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="hiddenContent">
  <div class="videoSel2">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/150052234"?autoplay=0&loop=0&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0 width="700" height="300" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="videoSel3">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/148650205"?autoplay=0&loop=0&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0 width="700" height="300" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead to  replace the div with the iframe inside try only to replace the iframe content:

```
$("div.videoSel2 > iframe").attr('src', $('.videoSel > iframe').attr('src'));
```

To handle the click event for the two yellow buttons you can do:

```
$('.arrowTop').on('click', function(e) {
   alert('ok');
});

$('.arrowBottom').on('click', function(e) {
   alert('ok');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! I have an extra question, I am trying to make the top and bottom arrow DIV's clickable but I cannot figure out how to do it. Tried that about event bubbling and using event propagate but it didn't work. The buttons are the two yellow buttons in my jsfiddle. Many thanks in advance :D

Comment: Many thanks once again, it's probably asking too much, but do you think you could have a look at my other thread? If not thank you very much for all the help you gave me.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485802/detect-when-div-has-reached-the-top-or-bottom